# How do I localize static UIApplicationShortcutItems?

Tags: ios, localization, 3dtouch

With the iPhone 6s, Apple has introduced a new feature called "3D Touch". App developers are able to use this technology by using it within their apps or provide so-called `UIApplicationShortcutItems` on the home screen which appear when you 3D Touch the corresponding app icon. I've seen quite a few people out there who wanted to know how you would be able to localize those. Here's how.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you have to do is, if you haven't already, create a new strings file called `InfoPlist.strings`, then you localize this strings file to the languages you wish via the File Inspector on the right.

Now, you write down a key (for example: `ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_TITLE` or `ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_DESCRIPTION`) and the correct translation for each localized file. For example:

**English file:**

```
ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_TITLE = "Add";
ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_DESCRIPTION = "a new item";
```

**German file:**

```
ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_TITLE = "Füge hinzu";
ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_DESCRIPTION = "ein neues Item";
```

Then, go to your Info.plist and enter your key to the corresponding field. For example:

[image: how your info.plist could look like here]

That way, you get localized `UIApplicationShortcutItems`. Now, they look like this:

**Phone language English:**

[image]

**Phone language German:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sam0711er answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798593/15767842)

If you have a lot of `UIApplicationShortcutItems`, then just write down the necessary unique names at the end, for example (in `InfoPlist.strings`):

```
ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_TITLE_SHARE = "Share app";
ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_TITLE_SOMETHING = "Something wrong?";
```

And in `Info.plist`:

[image]